# Google Maps React Native Android pricing

Tags: android, react-native, maps

Google Maps is extremely expensive so for our Android version we are using Thunderforest tiles.

We are using the code below. And we use https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps for Maps

My question is; with this code will this use any of the Google Maps APIs? Thus will I be charged for using it?

```
<MapView style={styles.map}
        ref={map => mapRef = map}
        showsBuildings={false}
        showsTraffic={false}
        showsCompass={false}
        rotateEnabled={false}
        pitchEnabled={false}
        toolbarEnabled={false}
        userInterfaceStyle='light'
        mapType={Platform.OS == "android" ? "none" : "standard"}
        showsPointsOfInterest={false}
        customMapStyle={CUSTOM_MAP_STYLE}
        onPress={() => setHasMoved(true)}
        onPanDrag={() => setHasMoved(true)}
        onRegionChange={(region) => {
          dispatch(setRegion(region))
        }}
        mapPadding={{
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 50, // TODO: padding when nearby is selected
          left: 0
        }}
      >
        {Platform.OS === 'android' ?
          <UrlTile
            urlTemplate='https://tile.thunderforest.com/atlas/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=XXXXXXX'
          />
        : null}

        <UserMarker />
      </MapView>
```